# How to include an html page in another page and have its contents be crawlable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, seo

I need to include an html page inside another html page, and I want the contents of the included page (page2.html) to be indexed by google.  I know iframes are not the solution, but how well do search engines handle html objects:

```
document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = '<object type="text/html" data="page2.html"></object>';
```

vs jQuery:

```
$(function(){$("#content").load("page2.html"); });
// <script type="text/javascript" src="../common_files/js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>  <-- in header
```

for html:

```
<div id="content"></div>
```

?  Or is there another better solution?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do it in the back end code

Comment: Or use SSI on the server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no 100% guarantee that content will be crawled by google if you use javascript/jquery.

You need to do it on server side.
In PHP you can use file_get_contents function to get page2.html

$homepage = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/page2.html');

and put $homepage variable into first page.